# NHibernate: How to specify criteria when fetching many-to-many?

Tags: nhibernate

The idea is to get all groups and fetch members. I have problems fetching only active users. Can you help me?

**Mapping:**

```
public class GroupDtoMap : DtoClassMap<GroupDto>
{
    public GroupDtoMap()
    {
        Id(g => g.Id, "group_id");
        HasManyToMany(g => g.Members) //  Members is a List<UserDto>
            .Table("members")
            .ParentKeyColumn("group_id")
            .ChildKeyColumn("user_id");
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
var groups = Session
            .CreateCriteria<GroupDto>()
                .Add(Expression.Eq("IsActive", true)) // Get only active groups
                .SetFetchMode("Members", NHibernate.FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                .Future<GroupDto>();
```

**What I tried but still failing:**

```
HasManyToMany(g => g.Members)
            .Table("members")
            .ParentKeyColumn("group_id")
            .ChildKeyColumn("user_id")
            .ChildWhere("status = 1");// the column in DB is 'status' with values 0/1
```

**EDIT:**
OK. It looks like the ChildWhere() is actually working. It was a nasty cache. The problem now is how to force inner join fetching the collection. At the moment it is doing left outer join. Any ideas?

Comment: is the status column on the members table?

Comment: HQL is much easier and more flexible for such queries. (`size`, `exists`, `elements` etc. See the reference manual: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-expressions)

Comment: I think that it is even harder to write this query with HQL :|

Comment: With this hql I get the correct sql but Members property is not initialized: Session
                            .CreateQuery(@" select gr, member from GroupDto as gr
                                            inner join fetch gr.Members as member
                                            where gr.IsActive = true and member.Id != null ")
                            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                            .Future<GroupDto>()

Comment: when you filter on the joined columns fetch is ignored because it might not return all childs to populate the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cant. Sorry.But you can allways try to play with the mappings